# Azure Deploy Fails

Tags: .net, azure, nuget

I am new to Azure and trying to set up a website there. I've got it hooked up to receive pushes from a local git repo, and it tries to deploy when I push, but the deploy fails with the following error message.

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http.Formatting". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\YoungNeedlesGames.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Http". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\YoungNeedlesGames.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Http.WebHost". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\YoungNeedlesGames.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\YoungNeedlesGames.csproj]
Global.asax.cs(4,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\YoungNeedlesGames.csproj]
App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs(1,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\YoungNeedlesGames.csproj]
App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs(7,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\YoungNeedlesGames.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\YoungNeedlesGames.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d4f6334a2b33d7";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\65.60827.2986\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

It looks like it's not restoring the nuget packages before trying to build, but that's just a guess. I created a new MVC project with Visual Studio and haven't made any big changes.

Comment: As you mentioned, it seems that you need to restore the nuget pack before msbuild. Have you referenced  this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#msbuild-integrated-restore)?

Comment: I've resolved this issue, but to be honest I'm not sure how. I ended up restarting the project from the beginning and using a github repo instead of a local one and doing source control via SourceTree rather than VS Community. The issue still seemed to be happening so I manually added the /packages folder by removing it from .gitignore. That caused some other issues, so I added /packages back to .gitignore and removed that folder from my github repo, and suddenly Azure was restoring nuget packages for me. I have no idea why, so I'm not going to consider this question answered, but I'm up.